# Firefox Addon to follow links by keyboard?

Tags: firefox, vimperator

I like the "Hit-a-hint like navigation of links (start with f to follow a link)" feature of vimperator, but using that addon breaks some sites for me. And though I use Vim as an editor, I don't really need it in my browser.

Does anyone know of a Firefox Addon that does just that hit-a-hint like navigation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wondering what "hit-a-hint" meant, I ran across [HaH](http://hah.mozdev.org/). Maybe that does what you call "hit-a-hint"?

> Pressing a specified button will activate a HaH-mode (Hit-a-Hint), which means that all "clickable" elements in the area will get a hovering hint over them. This hint has a number, and when that number is entered, the corresponing element is to be "clicked".

Not sure why the screenshot shows letters though, not numbers. Or how it would know that, after pressing a letter like "L", you might, or might not, want to type yet another letter:

[image: Funny navigation in HaH]

Update: Marten found [LoL](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/8781/), the successor of the old HaH.

Comment: Thanks. HaH is no longer maintained, but it's fork LoL seems like it does what I'm after.

Comment: @Marten, thanks for teaching me the term "hit-a-hint" today ;-)

Answer (score 1):

What about Vim Vixen?

> Vim Vixen is a Firefox add-on which allows you to easily navigate the
> web by keyboard. Since version 57, Firefox has migrated to the
> WebExtensions API and has dropped support for legacy add-ons. Vim
> Vixen is a new choice for Vim users since it uses the WebExtensions
> API.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/vim-vixen/

[image]